# Writing data to xml without for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml, nopcommerce

I am working on NopCommerce 2.40, and trying to generate sitemap using c# to submit it to google webmaster tools.

My code

```
_writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            _writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            _writer.WriteStartDocument();
            _writer.WriteStartElement("urlset");
            _writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
            _writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            _writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi:schemaLocation", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd");

            GenerateUrlNodes();

            _writer.WriteEndElement();
            _writer.Close();
```

In this GenerateUrlNodes() method different methods are called 
e.g

```
            WriteStores();
            WriteStoresCategories();
            WriteStoresProducts();
```

In third method of writing store products.

```
foreach (var store in stores)
            {

                //TODO add a method for getting URL (use routing because it handles all SEO friendly URLs)
                 if (store.Id != 1)
                 {
                         var products = _productService.SearchProducts(0, 0, null, null, null, 0, null, false, 1, new List<int>(), ProductSortingEnum.Position, 0, int.MaxValue, store.Id, false);
                         foreach (var product in products)
                         {
                             var url = string.Format("{0}s/{1}/{2}/p/{3}/{4}", _webHelper.GetStoreLocation(false), store.Id, store.GetSeName(), product.Id, product.GetSeName());
                             var updateFrequency = UpdateFrequency.Weekly;
                             var updateTime = product.UpdatedOnUtc;
                             WriteUrlLocation(url, updateFrequency, updateTime);


                         }

                 }
            }
```

Its taking too time as there are Multiple stores with 5 to 6k of products in each store. So when I try to submit this sitemap to google its throwing error of timeout. Is there any way to optimize this or avoiding for loop to generate xml

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: The fundamental problem here seems not to be the fact that there is a loop, but rather that it is simply taking too long. I am particularly intrigued by `_webHelper.GetStoreLocation(false)` and `store.GetSeName()` - are those going out to external resources? the first looks like an http fetch; the second could be a db fetch; if so: I suggest *that* is the thing you need to remove, for example by pre-fetching all of those in one hit rather than per-product.

Comment: Also: `_productService.SearchProducts`; again, if there are a number of stores, that could have significant impact; it does, however, look to be trivially parallelizable around `stores`

Comment: @MarcGravell the one suggestion with GetSeName() and GetStoreLocation() is awesome. will do that right now!

Comment: it actually looks like `_webHelper.GetStoreLocation(false)` could be moved outside of both loops

Comment: Yep u r right I have done that

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to do here is to remove redundancy. It looks like you call `_webHelper.GetStoreLocation(false)` once per product, and `store.GetSeName()` twice per product - but neither depends on the product. So as an immediate thing:

```
var location = _webHelper.GetStoreLocation(false);
foreach (var store in stores)
{
     var seName = store.GetSeName();
    //TODO add a method for getting URL (use routing because it handles all SEO friendly URLs)
     if (store.Id != 1)
     {
         var products = _productService.SearchProducts(0, 0, null, null, null, 0, null, false, 1, new List<int>(), ProductSortingEnum.Position, 0, int.MaxValue, store.Id, false);
         foreach (var product in products)
         {
             var url = string.Format("{0}s/{1}/{2}/p/{3}/{4}", location, store.Id, seName, product.Id, seName);
             var updateFrequency = UpdateFrequency.Weekly;
             var updateTime = product.UpdatedOnUtc;
             WriteUrlLocation(url, updateFrequency, updateTime);
         }
     }
}
```

The `SearchProducts` is clearly per-store, since it involves `store.Id`, so we can't promote that; however, it looks like the `stores` loop is trivially parallelizable; if this is making http calls, for example, it would be well worth investigating `Parallel.ForEach` here, but the problem then becomes ordering and concurrency; you might need to use `Parallel` to create the *result* of each (as a string or similar), and then **when all the strings are available**, loop over them doing the actual writes - thus preserving the original order.

Comment: cant i use paralleforeach for products inside as well?

Comment: Used parallelforeach but its throwing me connection to db closed exceptions

Comment: @NitinVarpe parallelization should be done in big chunks; better to parallelize stores, not products; there is hardly ever any advantage to parallelizing inside parallelization. As for the DB code: I can't comment on that without the DB code - it isn't even obvious which parts of that **are** DB related